# Create TypeToken for type argument of generic super type

Tags: java, android, generics, gson, typetoken

I'm implementing a Gson `TypeAdapter` for two dependend generic models.

```
interface ModelA<T> {}
interface ModelB<T> extends ModelA<List<T>> {}
```

For this I need to get the `TypeToken` and `TypeAdapter`. By doing

```
Type type = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
TypeToken<?> token = TypeToken.get(type);
TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(token);
```

I get a type token for both models of any given type `AnyType` and the correlating adapter. This is what I need for `ModelA`, but for `ModelB` I'd need the adapter for `List<AnyType>` instead, which is the result of using `ModelA<List<AnyType>>` directly.

Using the interface of the raw type of the original type token passed

```
token.getRawType().getGenericInterfaces()[0]
```

I only seem to get the type erased type of `List`.

How can I combine these two informations to get the generic `List<AnyType>` type or create it directly? As input it only has the type token for `ModelB<AnyType>`.

#### Example

For the given behavior I implemented a simple test showing the differences. I've taken the `expected` part from the answer by *hahn*, using the Gson internal non-API class `$Gson$Types`.

```
public class TypeTokenValidate {

    public interface ModelA<T> {}
    public interface ModelB<T> extends ModelA<List<T>> {}

    @Test
    public void genericToken() throws Exception {
        TypeToken<ModelB<String>> token = new TypeToken<ModelB<String>>() {};
        ModelB<String> m = new ModelB<String>() {};
        Type expected = $Gson$Types.resolve(ModelB.class, m.getClass(),
                ModelA.class.getTypeParameters()[0]);
        assertEquals(expected, getActual(token));
    }

    private static Type getActual(TypeToken<?> token) {
        Type type = token.getType();
        //type = token.getRawType().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
        type = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return TypeToken.get(type).getType();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean that that ```token.getRawType().getGenericInterfaces()[0]``` is not castable into ParametrizedType? If it is, you just go on recursively.

Comment: It is, but `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` doesn't seem to have the generic type information. Thus I only get `List` without any information about `T`

Comment: We know that ```java.util.List``` has a type parameter so if you were to use reflection directly to List.class then the info should be there, right?

Comment: Reflections don't provide any information about generics. I think that's the issue with the raw type, since it's a `Class<?>` type and therefore erases the generic types on runtime.

Comment: What do you get the appropriate ````type```  for ModelB or ModelA? Isn't that ModelB.class.getTypeParameters()? Could you add that to your question code? What is List.class.getTypeParameters() gives you?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `$Gson$Types` that you can utilize to retrieve `Type` of typed `List`. For example having:

```
ModelB<String> m = new ModelB<String>() {};
Type resolve = $Gson$Types.resolve(m.getClass(), m.getClass(), ModelA.class.getTypeParameters()[0]);
```

would return `Type` with `rawType` set to `List` and with `typeArguments` of `[String]`. Thus preserving the types as you need.

and then executing this block

```
TypeToken<?> token = TypeToken.get(resolve);
TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(token);
```

would result with adaptor of `CollectionTypeAdaptorFactory` with `elementTypeAdapter.type` set to class `String`.

Comment: This seems to work fine, but is there any way to do this without using the internal class `$Gson$Types` directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `.getType()` rather than `.getRawType()` the information that you are looking for seems to be preserved:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Test  {

   public interface ModelA<T> {};

   public interface ModelB<T> extends ModelA<List<T>> {}

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Using java.lang.reflect.*:

        System.out.println(ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]);
        // out: Test.Test$ModelA<java.util.List<T>>
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType)ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        // out: java.util.List<T>
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType)((ParameterizedType)ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        // out: T

        // Recovery from a TokenType instance...

        // ... using .getRawType()
        System.out.println(TypeToken.get(ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getRawType());
        // out: interface Test$ModelA
        System.out.println(TypeToken.get(((ParameterizedType)((ParameterizedType)ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0])).getRawType());
        // out: interface java.util.List

        // ... using .getType()
        System.out.println(TypeToken.get(ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getType());
        // out: Test$ModelA<java.util.List<T>>
        System.out.println(TypeToken.get(((ParameterizedType)((ParameterizedType)ModelB.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0])).getType());
        // out: java.util.List<T>
   }
}
```

Hopefully you can figure out how to create your `TokenAdaptors` from there.

Comment: How can I do this with a non generic `T` like `String`? This only differs in the implementation of `toString()`. I updated my question, since it was not totally clear.

Comment: @tynn If the <String> part you trying to recover *is just* present in the declaration of a variable or some other non-class creating expression like the construction call... that information is lost at run-time; You cannot expect to pull it from any X.class instance or any instance. The reason why hahn's solution works is because he is declaring an inner class with the <String> in its declaration therefore he can mine the info. Depends on your circumstances that might be enough for you but such a solution won't be able to handle arbitrary models constructed in run-time without a trailing "{}".

Comment: @tynn besides the solution I propose would also work on a inner class; I have not tested it by I don't see why it wouldn't work.